# charge commission/fee on every DEX transaction using 0x API

Tags: 0x, decentralized-exchange, exchange-api

I would Like to charge commission/fee on every DEX transaction using 0x API; i am calling
`GET /swap/v1/quote`

with adding `feeRecipient` & `buyTokenPercentageFee` but when a user does a tranx via the API on our UI platform; we are NOT getting any fee.

Should i be using any other API in combination to above? or ...

**Query string:**

`https://bsc.api.0x.org/swap/v1/quote?sellToken=BNB&buyToken=DAI&buyAmount=10000000000000000&feeRecipient=0x4519dE0a438aaBBD56f1f268F60325c85250062B&takerAddress=0x4519dE0a438aaBBD56f1f268F60325c85250062B&buyTokenPercentageFee=0.15`

Please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have `feeRecipient` set to the same address as the `takerAddress`. This means `0x4519dE0a438aaBBD56f1f268F60325c85250062B` is effectively paying themselves the commission.

Comment: Hey; i just entered this query string hastily; during tranx `takerAddress` != `feeRecipient ` and the `feeRecipient` still doesnt receive anything

I hope the query string is enough right? no other API needs to be called?

Comment: In that case the query looks correct, no other API is necessary. Do you have an example transaction?